# Laravel Mailer - maximum memory limit exceeded?

Tags: php, email, laravel, exception, vagrant

I'm trying to get my Laravel app to send me an email whenever there's an error in production. Basically it goes:

```
App::error(function(Exception $exception, $code)
{
    if (App::environment('local')) {    // not testing this on prod, duh
        Event::fire('error.production', [$exception, $code]);

        return View::make('error.default');
    }
});
```

That 'error.production' event just goes to an error handler that sends an email:

```
public function handle($exception, $code)
{
    $result = $this->mailer
      ->setView('emails.error.production')
      ->setSubject('Production Error')
      ->setToAddress('me@myself.com')
      ->setToName('patricksaysi')
      ->setData(['exception' => $exception, 'code' => $code])
      ->send();

    return $result;
}
```

The email sends, but the execution cycle never completes to the extent that it's actually able to display the error screen to the user. This is because another error is occurring when I send the email - `Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 532414464 bytes)`.

I've set a breakpoint on the `return $result` line in the `handle()` function above, and it is never reached. I've tried stepping through the SwiftMailer "send" cycle, and I can say it's gigantic and takes forever and I learned nothing from it, other than that it's maybe a likely candidate for the cause of the memory allocation error. I'm running this on Laravel Homestead so in theory the environment should be optimal. It's a very simple email / view, just spits out the error body and code. Any ideas what could be going wrong? Is there a better way to accomplish what I'm trying to do here?

Comment: Possibly an infinite loop. Debug `$exception` and `$code` instead of firing the event to see what's up.. could be something simple.

Comment: Well, the first `$exception` is "Target interface is not instantiable", because to test this I just commented out the body of a service provider. However, it does enter a loop after the first `memory exceeded` error is thrown, because the app then keeps trying to handle a new error, sending the same email, getting the same result.